# How to create a div after 4 elements in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I Hope You Are Good

I want to show my city in my footer

I want 4 cities in each div after 4 cities added in div I want to create a new div and add 4 cities and so on

here is the html reffrence:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6">
            
    <p><a href="/property/listings/?city=islamabad" class="fot-text">Islamabad</a></p>
    
    <p><a href="/property/listings/?city=karachi" class="fot-text">Karachi</a></p>
    
    <p><a href="/property/listings/?city=lahore" class="fot-text">Lahore</a></p>
    
    <p><a href="/property/listings/?city=rawalpindi" class="fot-text">Rawalpindi</a></p>
    
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6">
    
    <p><a href="/property/listings/?city=Abbottabad" class="fot-text">Abbottabad</a></p>
    
    <p><a href="/property/listings/?city=Abdul Hakim" class="fot-text">Abdul Hakim</a></p>
    
    <p><a href="/property/listings/?city=Ahmedpur East" class="fot-text">Ahmedpur East</a></p>
    
    <p><a href="/property/listings/?city=Alipur" class="fot-text">Alipur</a></p>
    
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6">
    
    <p><a href="/property/listings/?city=Arifwala" class="fot-text">Arifwala</a></p>
    
    <p><a href="/property/listings/?city=Astore" class="fot-text">Astore</a></p>
    
    <p><a href="/property/listings/?city=Attock" class="fot-text">Attock</a></p>
    
    <p><a href="/property/listings/?city=Awaran" class="fot-text">Awaran</a></p>
    
</div>
```

I want to like this HTML

how can I achieve this!

the following code dosen't work:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6">
    {% for city in citys %}
        <p><a href="/property/listings/?city={{ city }}" class="fot-text">{{ city }}</a></p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

it adds all element in one div

how can create new div after 4 items added on that div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forloop.counter`

```
{% for city in citys %}
    {% if forloop.first %} 
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6">
            <p><a href="/property/listings/?city={{ city }}" class="fot-text">{{ city }}</a></p>
    {% elif forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" and not forloop.last %}
            <p><a href="/property/listings/?city={{ city }}" class="fot-text">{{ city }}</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6">
    {% elif not forloop.last %}
            <p><a href="/property/listings/?city={{ city }}" class="fot-text">{{ city }}</a></p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            </div>
        {% else %}
                <p><a href="/property/listings/?city={{ city }}" class="fot-text">{{ city }}</a></p>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '%' from '%'

Comment: Indeed, i fix it, try now.

Comment: please change ) to } in your else

Comment: @HamzaMirchi, Of course, I also changed the logic for processing the last record.

Comment: @HamzaMirchi, Glad to hear, be aware to use my last edit version where i've added check in first `elif`, that `forloop.counter` is not last `{% elif forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" and not forloop.last %}`

Answer (score 0):

try this

[Make List Tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#make-list) will help you.

```
{% for i in '0123'|make_list %}
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6">
        {% for city in citys %}
              <p><a href="/property/listings/?city={{ city }}" class="fot-text">{{ city }}</a></p>
        {% endfor %}
   </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: it's creating only 3 div imagine if i had 100 citys then what